# App not starting after Next Button

Tags: android

I'm making an app for android. This is a messenger. I have made it,  but the prob is that when I click the first next button, it closes and says, "Unfortunately, FirstApp has stopped". I am making it in Eclipse IDE but whenever I click it, it says the same, I'll upload the code after you say which code I've to upload. 
This is my code in MainActivity.java:

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = (new Intent(MainActivity.this, TermsConditionsStarting.class));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

LogCat-

```
01-25 23:37:10.058: W/ActivityThread(29794): Application com.example.firstapp2014 can be debugged on port 8100...
01-25 23:37:10.158: I/Adreno-EGL(29794): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
01-25 23:37:10.198: D/OpenGLRenderer(29794): Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 23:37:16.534: D/AndroidRuntime(29794): Shutting down VM
01-25 23:37:16.534: W/dalvikvm(29794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ecba8)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): Process: com.example.firstapp2014, PID: 29794
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    ... 11 more
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.firstapp2014/com.example.firstapp2014.TermsConditionsStarting}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    at com.example.firstapp2014.MainActivity.openNewActivity(MainActivity.java:26)
01-25 23:37:16.534: E/AndroidRuntime(29794):    ... 14 more
01-25 23:37:17.755: I/Process(29794): Sending signal. PID: 29794 SIG: 9
01-25 23:41:23.695: W/ActivityThread(30141): Application com.example.firstapp2014 can be debugged on port 8100...
01-25 23:41:23.805: I/Adreno-EGL(30141): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
01-25 23:41:23.835: D/OpenGLRenderer(30141): Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 23:41:24.806: D/AndroidRuntime(30141): Shutting down VM
01-25 23:41:24.806: W/dalvikvm(30141): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ecba8)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Process: com.example.firstapp2014, PID: 30141
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    ... 11 more
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.firstapp2014/com.example.firstapp2014.TermsConditionsStarting}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    at com.example.firstapp2014.MainActivity.openNewActivity(MainActivity.java:26)
01-25 23:41:24.806: E/AndroidRuntime(30141):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Have you added the `TermsConditionsStarting` in the AndroidManifest.xml and post the logcat

Comment: and please post the complete class.

Comment: "Unfortunately, [your app] has stopped" is code speak. It means "Read the Logcat"

Comment: Speaking of Terms and Conditions : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195939/minimum-age-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Post the layout file, too

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? Either way, the LogCat will show the exact problem that causes your program to crash. In order to help you, we will need information from the logcat.

Comment: Added the LogCat. Now anything more to add?

Comment: @Dhairyadev  `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`. It says you need to declare `TermsConditionsStarting` activity in your manifest file.

Comment: Umm... can you please comment the whole thing i need to add in manifest file? and also where.. thnks! :)

Comment: Thanks dude, that worked! but its moving to another page. It's showing "Hello World!". What to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `TermsConditionsStarting` activity in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".TermsConditionsStarting" />
```

Comment: how do you know the reason of the crash?

Comment: Oh, c'mon! he just did a supposition... he wants to help, like us.

Comment: He found out by this line - android.content.ActivityNotFoundException in stack trace